# analitycs solutions to the equation $f'(x)=f(x)f(x-1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

As the title says I'm serching for functions ($C^n$ or analitycs $f$) that satisfies

$f'(x)=f(x)f(x-1)$

---

***some details***: I've come at this equation after looking for a function $g$ satisfying for some given $h$

$g'(g^{-1}(x))=x\cdot h(x)$

I tried to manipulate the equation

$g'(g^{-1}(g(x)))=g(x)\cdot h(g(x))$

And since I assume (define)that $h(g(x))=g(x-1)$ holds the equation should turn into

$g'(x)=g(x)g(x-1)$

Comment: I think it's obvious that no non-constant polynomial $f(x)$ can satisfy this equation, as $f'(x)$ is a polynomial of lower degree than $f(x)$, and $f(x)f(x−1)$ is a polynomial of higher degree than $f(x)$. As to constant polynomials, it's obvious that $f(x)=0$ is the only solution. So apart from this solution, you should probably look for non-polynomial functions.

Comment: @barakmanos ah ok, well.. then what about special functions or conbination of those? At the beginning I was hoping for solutions of that kind (gamma function-like)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f(x)$ for $x\in[0,1]$ to be anything.
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=f(x-1)\\
\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\int f(x-1)dx\\
\ln(f(x))+c=\int f(x-1) dx\\
f(x)=A\exp(\int f(x-1) dx)$$
Then, since you already know $f(1)$, 
$$f(x)=f(1)\exp(\int_1^x f(t-1)dt)$$ 
defines $f(x)$ for $x\in[1,2]$

Comment: I'm really sorry but can you expand you answer a little bit? I'm not really good with calculus and differential equations, so maybe you could explain me the deduction and show me the steps, thank you in advance.

Comment: The constant $A$ is meant to be $e^{-c}$? Anyways at the and I get only a function defined on $[0,2]$? Sorry but I'm worse than I expected at this, I'm not very familiar with integrals...

Comment: Then repeat the process to get a function defined on $[2,3]$, and again for $[3,4]$.  Sorry, that's all I've got.  Actually $A=\pm e^{-c}$ because the previous integral should be $|\ln(f(x))|+c$.

Comment: Does $f(x)=1/(1-\{x\})$ count, where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$?  It is discontinuous at integers.

Comment: well, it works. Even if I was serching for some nicer function, but you showed that one can use every function on $[0,1]$ and define it picewise, in that case nvm, there is not even unicity (even up to integration costant).